# Can't fadeout when using CSS3 rotate

Tags: jquery, html, css, rotation, transform

I've come across a rather strange issue with Google Chrome. I cannot fadeout a H1 element when I've applied CSS3 transform (rotate). This seems like a weird issue i cannot get around other than using images. Does anybody know a way to fix this, I don't want to hack this with images if I don't have to.

Here is the CSS for that particular H1

```
.studieprogramLinje h1{
color:#fff;
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
 transform: rotate(90deg);
 white-space: nowrap;
 margin-top:270px;
 font-weight: 100;
 }
```

And the JQuery part is just:

```
$('#mobilApputvikling h1').fadeOut(200);
```

It seems to be working if I fade out ALL h1 elements like this:

```
$('h1').fadeOut(200);
```

But not with this particular one. It however works if I remove the rotation in CSS3..

Comment: You should provide a test link or better a jsfiddle

Comment: I've tried that, but rotate doesn't seem to work in JSFiddle.

Comment: Rotate (CSS3) should work on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the jQuery animate instead?  Will probably have the same effect, but might be a work around.

```
$('h1').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 200);
```

If there isn't a work around, how about submitting the bug: [Chromium Bugs](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines)

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that aswell. Forgot to mention that - either way it still doesn't work. Nothing is happening.

Comment: I thought about that, perhaps I should. What a weird issue! It seems to be the same for Safari, so it might be a webkit issue. I'll dive into it, and hack it with images for now! Thanks for you answers!